# Reflection Field setValue for inner object

Tags: java, reflection

```
class User{
  Account account;
  String name; 
}

class Account {
  Integer amount;
}


**main :**
        User u = new User();
        Field field = u.getClass().getDeclaredField("account");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field amount = field.getType().getDeclaredField("amount");
        amount.set(field, new Integer(1000));
```

console :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
 java.math.BigDecimal field com.company.Account.amount to java.lang.reflect.Field
```

How to set value into Account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an object of type `Account`, populate it (either directly or through reflection) and use it to set the `account` field of your `User` instance.

```
User u = new User();

Field field = u.getClass().getDeclaredField("account");
field.setAccessible(true);  

Account account = new Account();
account.amount = new Integer(1000);

field.set(u, account);
```

As always, the javadoc explains how [`Field#set(Object, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) works.

> Sets the field represented by this `Field` object on the specified
>   object argument to the specified new value. The new value is
>   automatically unwrapped if the underlying field has a primitive type.

Comment: I have tried this approach, but I am searching another one because actually I have a complex business object with plenty of fields, it's annoying to populate all of them in order to change one field, i my example it's amount.

Comment: @play You don't have a choice. There are no shortcuts. You either do it directly or through reflection. `Field#set` works with instances.